# Fetch custom exception from the exchange

Tags: apache-camel

I have declared my CustomException class.
When the onException() catches it , it goes to the processor I defined :

```
onException(classOf[CustomException]).process(doSmth)
```

So far so good .
The issue that I need into the processor to check if the exception is of type "CustomException" or not

when I write :

def process(exchange: Exchange) = {
    val exception: CustomException= exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, classOf[CustomException])

**I got null**

But when I write :

```
def process(exchange: Exchange) = {
    val exception: Exception = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, classOf[Exception])
```

**I got my exception object**

How could I check which type of exception is thrown into the processor !

Answer (score 0):

in Java DSL, this works...

```
public void process(Exchange exch) throws Exception {
    Exception e = (Exception) exch.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT);
    if (e instanceof CustomException) {
        logger.info("custom exception");
    } else {
        logger.info("other excpetion");
    }
}
```